Train Tesseract 5.3.3
I need Tesseract to recognize characters on receipts. The problem is that the OCR struggles a lot to recognize the textual information on the images.
I would like to train Tesseract so that it succeeds in transcribing as faithfully as possible the information available on various receipts. I can't find any information on the existing documentation on how to successfully do this. Is it possible ? If yes comment?
